# how to convert a DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.shape into a HTML SVG element

Tags: openxml-sdk

I need a sample code for converting DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.shape into a HTML SVG element in .net.  Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.
RagesH.

Answer (score 0):

If the presentation has shapes stored as a WMF image, then you can pass the images as a file or stream and convert it to SVG format. There are tools to convert WMF2SVG. 
Refer this page.
This is for Java https://code.google.com/p/wmf2svg/

For using it with .NET, you have to convert this Jar into DLL and use it.

For Converting Jar into DLL refer this https://code.google.com/p/jar2ikvmc/

This works for me.
Hope this helps!